# Geometry similarity problem

Tags: geometry

> Find the length $\overline{WA}$.

[image]

Easily we can see that $\overline{XW}$ and $\overline{WY}$ are both $\frac{5}{2}$ and that $\bigtriangleup XZY$ ~ $\bigtriangleup XAW$. What I don't see is that how do I utilise this similarity to find $\overline{WA}$?

Comment: Similar triangles have proportional sides, hence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{WA}{4}=\dfrac{\frac{5}{2}}{3}$